# Outlook appointment using ActiveX

Tags: javascript, outlook, outlook-addin

I would like to set up outlook appointment using ActiveX.

Following code is working. Other than the part where I have setup the timezone. which i cant seem to find how to set. Is there any API reference available to setup timezone ?

```
 var sub = "Test";
                var stDate = "01-01-2020";
                var endDate = "01-01-2020";
                var sBody1 = ".....";
                var sBody2 = "hello ";
                var sBody3 = ".....world";
                if (confirm("Are you sure that you want to send an outlook invite for the meeting? Click OK to send invite.")) {
                    try {
                        outlookApp = new ActiveXObject("outlook.application");
                    }
                    catch (Error) {
                        alert("Please verify if your browser is enabled to run ActiveX scripts and try again!");
                        return false;
                    }

                    try {
                        nameSpace = outlookApp.getNameSpace("MAPI");
                        mailFolder = nameSpace.getDefaultFolder(6);
                        mailItem = mailFolder.Items.Add("IPM.Appointment.ConfRmReq");
                        mailItem.MeetingStatus = 1;
                        mailItem.Subject = sub;
                        mailItem.Start = stDate;
                        mailItem.End = endDate;

                        mailItem.TimeZones = ["Eastern Standard Time"];
                        //var tzEastern = tzs["Eastern Standard Time"];

                        mailItem.StartTimeZone = tzEastern;
                        mailItem.EndTimeZone = tzEastern;

                        var sBody = sBody1;
                        mailItem.Body = sBody;

                        sEmailList.push('Email Address');
                        mailItem.RequiredAttendees = sEmailList.join(';');
                        mailItem.Display();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to retrieve the timezone from the `Application.Iimezones` collection. I never had luck retrieving the tz by its name, so you'd need to enumerate the time zones and check their `ID` / `Name` / `StandardDesignation` / `DaylightDesignation` properties.

Comment: Hi Will it be possible for you to give some code.... I can iterate the timezones. but don't know how do i set up them

Comment: on each step of the iteration, check if the above mentioned properties are equal to the value you are matching against. If yes, save the matching tz in an variable and break from the loop.